# Sql Timeout when converting IEnumerable<T> to List<T> in C# Entityframework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, ienumerable

There are around 2800 records fetched from database in 2 sec with following code

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecWithStoreProcedure(string query, params object[] parameters)
{
        return db.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query, parameters);
}
```

but when converting to list, Sql Timeout comes. I am using EntityFramework with SQL database. How to achieve Performance in less than 15 sec.

Comment: A badly written query will always be slow. If you can't *connect* to the database though, you'd still get a timeout connection. What you posted doesn't show anything. Post the *full* connection including the call stack (returned by Exception.ToString()). This will show whether this was a connection or execution timeout. Also post the *query itself* and its execution plan

Comment: I wonder why it needs 2 seconds to call this method, how have you measured it? Should return almost immediately. `SqlQuery` will return just the query which is not yet executed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's impossible to optimize a sql query which isn't shown and without necessary informations like the query plan

Comment: how long it takes to call `db.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query, parameters).First()`?

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework uses lazy evaluation, meaning that simply calling `SqlQuery` doesn't actually *perform* the query, it simply builds it. Only when the IQueryable/IEnumerable is materialized, that's when the actual query is performed. So when you call ToList(), that's the point where your query is executed.

As to why it's slow - that's up to the query itself. No way to tell from the code here.

Comment: IQueryable is derived from IEnumerable. Simply returning it as IEnumerable<T> won't necessarily perform anything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Are you saying that casting an object somehow runs a function on it. In this case to execute the query?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - seems you missed OP's statement `but when converting to list` - so a `.ToList()` call is causing the SQL exception

Comment: The opposite. Calling ToList() executes the query, so you get the SQL Exception. Casting to IEnumerable doesn't exeute the query, so no SQL Exception. The SQL Exception has nothing to do with the cast or with ToList, it's simply a slow query.

Comment: Facepalm. Bad coffee

Comment: It is stored procedure and but when run in backend it just takes 2-3 sec to execute the SP and get the data. Problem is when converting toList. it takes too much time (min 1 Min) and after that SQL Timeout comes. I have no issue increasing CommandTimeout in code but it is bad approach. Data mostly of type String and that is to 50-100 char. In model I have total 25 fields.

Comment: I agree that increasing the timeout is a bad solution to the problem. If the query itself is fast when run in SQL directly, the slowness is probably when creating the models from the data.

Answer (score 1):

try using this  in your method befor fire a query command

this.context.CommandTimeout = 180;